# Highcharts Export without internet

Tags: highcharts, export, png, offline

In my project/setup, both client & server doesn't have Internet connectivity.

Any idea how to export data as .PNG or .JPG  since **export.highcharts.com** wont be accessible.

Answer (score 4):

You can prepaer your own exporting server http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts

Answer (score 1):

You can also use offline exporting - you'll need to download and locally reference the offline-exporting.js (http://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js) file, and you may need other libraries - like canvg https://code.google.com/p/canvg - if you want to export to png).

Please see http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export for details.